# sql Syntax error. missing operator in sql

Tags: sql

I wrote an SQL query to join 6 tables. But when i run it gives me an error as "Syntax error. missing operator "
My sql query is as follows.

```
SELECT (r.officerName, r.Department, b.title, q.committee_No, cd.selected_bidder, cd.status FROM reqesition r INNER JOIN books as b ON b.book_ID=r.reqesitionID INNER JOIN quotation as q ON q.quotationID=b.book_ID INNER JOIN comittee_decision as cd ON cd.decisionID=q.quotationID);
```

can pls anyone help me to find the error in here.

Comment: remove the parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT r.officerName, r.Department, b.title, q.committee_No, cd.selected_bidder, cd.status
    FROM reqesition AS r
    INNER JOIN books AS b ON b.book_ID = r.reqesitionID
    INNER JOIN quotation AS q ON q.quotationID = b.book_ID
    INNER JOIN comittee_decision AS cd ON cd.decisionID = q.quotationID
    LIMIT 1000;
```

*1)Removed the parentheses around the columns in the SELECT clause. You don't need parentheses when selecting multiple columns; just separate them with commas.
2)Fixed the spelling of "requisition" in the FROM clause.
3)Added table aliases (r, b, q, cd) for better readability and to avoid ambiguity in column names.*

Comment: Note that `select c1, c2 from t` returns two _columns_, but `select (c1, c2) from t` only returns one _column_ - a _row type_ column having two _fields_.